Grid Probability Filling with 1s
Is there any cleaner way of doing the following problem besides PIE?
Given a 3 x 4 grid, let each grid contain a 1 with probability p and 0 otherwise (indepdent). What is the probability that every row and every column contains at least one 1?

What's the PIE approach you have in mind? I'd try a brute force strategy starting with separate cases for the total number of 1s.
